# DynamoDB-PHP: error when region is not east coast

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I have a PHP application, using symfony2, silex, and the AWS DynamoDB SDK. It's been working fine. The DynamoDB is created on the East Coast.

We have a second AWS account, and we duplicated the DynamoDB structure (table names, table structures, etc. are all the same). This DynamoDB installation is on the West Coast (N. California).

My application does not work when we try to use the second AWS credentials.

When I try to do:

```
$res = $app['db']->describe_table(array('TableName' => 'account'));
```

and I dump $res, here's what I get:

```
CFResponse Object
(
[header] => Array
    (
        [x-amzn-requestid] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        [x-amz-crc32] => xxxxxxxxxxxxx
        [content-type] => application/x-amz-json-1.0
        [content-length] => 143
        [date] => Wed, 28 Nov 2012 20:49:31 GMT
        [_info] => Array
            (
                [url] => https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
                [content_type] => application/x-amz-json-1.0
                [http_code] => 400
                [header_size] => 224
                [request_size] => 896
                [filetime] => -1
                [ssl_verify_result] => 0
                [redirect_count] => 0
                [total_time] => 0.363967
                [namelookup_time] => 0.008497
                [connect_time] => 0.091183
                [pretransfer_time] => 0.263514
                [size_upload] => 28
                [size_download] => 143
                [speed_download] => 392
                [speed_upload] => 76
                [download_content_length] => 143
                [upload_content_length] => 0
                [starttransfer_time] => 0.363929
                [redirect_time] => 0
                [certinfo] => Array
                    (
                    )

                [redirect_url] => 
                [method] => POST
            )

        [x-aws-stringtosign] => AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
            20121128T204931Z
            20121128/us-east-1/dynamodb/aws4_request
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        [x-aws-canonicalrequest] => POST
            /
            content-length:28
            content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.0
            host:dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
            x-amz-date:20121128T204931Z
            x-amz-target:DynamoDB_20111205.DescribeTable
            content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        [x-aws-request-headers] => Array
            (
                [Content-Length] => 28
                [Content-Type] => application/x-amz-json-1.0
                [Host] => dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
                [X-Amz-Date] => 20121128T204931Z
                [X-Amz-Target] => DynamoDB_20111205.DescribeTable
                [Authorization] => AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJAIBF2DKGD2UD3YQ/20121128/us-east-1/dynamodb/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target,Signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                [Expect] => 
            )

        [x-aws-body] => {"TableName":"account"}
    )

[body] => CFSimpleXML Object
    (
        [__type] => com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20111205#ResourceNotFoundException
        [message] => Requested resource not found: Table: account not found
    )

[status] => 400
)
```

I thought that the only configuration required is in the AWS DynamoDB SDK, in the file config.inc.php, where I can only configure the credentials. This does not seem to be the case,as the response has all these references to the east coast and the DynamoDB table I'm targeting is on the West Coast. Any ideas how I can tell it the AmazonSDK to point to another region? Any other issues I should be concerned about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. It was buried in the docs (Amazon considers this product and its docs BETA).

Prior to using $app['db'], I need to do:

```
$app['db']->set_region('dynamodb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com');
```

or whatever region my DynamoDB was created in. Amazon provides some region constants as part of the amazonDynamodb class, but I'm having trouble using them. So, instead of 'dynamodb.us-west-1.amazonaws.com', you can use something like REGION_US_W1

It seems as if by default, the REGION_US_E1 is used, so if you're in that region, you probably don't need to set anything, but it might be wise to do so, as Amazon may modify the SDK classes.